# Problems interpreting a square wave

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to use an ESP8266 SoC to read a water flow sensor that is said to produce a square wave as output.  I thought it would be a simple matter of using a GPIO port in interrupt mode, to count rising edge transitions -- and in fact that initially seemed to work.  Then I upgraded the firmware from 0.96 to 1.5 and it has since ceased to work, I see no transitions when the wheel spins anymore.

However, if I run a wire to the pin [for the GPIO I'm using] and touch it to VCC momentarily, the interrupt routine is called as expected, so I know the sensor is wired to the right pin, and the interrupt routine is registered correctly.  My code:

```
function intCb(level)
    SpinCount = SpinCount + 1
    local levelString = "up"
    if level == gpio.HIGH then
        levelString = "down"
    end
    gpio.trig(pin, levelString, intCb)
end
gpio.write(pin, 0)
gpio.trig(pin, "up", intCb)
gpio.mode(pin, gpio.INT, gpio.FLOAT)
```

So what am I missing?  Do I need more support circuitry to read a square wave as input?  If so then how did it work initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using a 555 timer chip as a schmitt trigger:

[image: schematics]

Comment: Glad you got that fixed.

Answer (score 2):

For anything that involves hardware it's really hard to give a definite answer here on SO. In most cases one bases it on hints (and hunches sometimes). A few ideas:

- `gpio.FLOAT` should probably be [`gpio.PULLUP`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/gpio/#gpiomode) instead (unless you have an external pull-up resistor).
- Your setup doesn't seem to be fundamentally different from e.g. using a push button or a switch to trigger some event. Hence, you probably want to use some kind of debounce or throttle function.
- Since you seem to be interested in both rising *and* falling edges (as you switch between `up` and `down`) you might just as well listen for `both`, no?

So, assuming I drew the right conclusions something like the following [generic skeleton](https://gist.github.com/marcelstoer/59563e791effa4acb65f) may prove to be useful:

```lua
-- inspired by https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/blob/master/tutorials/introduction-to-gpio-api.md
-- and http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=4833&start=5#p29127
local pin = 4    --> GPIO2

function debounce (func)
    local last = 0
    local delay = 5000

    return function (...)
        local now = tmr.now()
        local delta = now - last
        -- if delta < 0 then delta = delta + 2147483647 end; proposed because of delta rolling over
        if delta < delay then return end;

        last = now
        return func(...)
    end
end

function onChange ()
    print('The pin value has changed to '..gpio.read(pin))
end

gpio.mode(pin, gpio.INT, gpio.PULLUP) -- see https://github.com/hackhitchin/esp8266-co-uk/pull/1
gpio.trig(pin, 'both', debounce(onChange))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply (if I'm allowed to say that) that's interesting but I'm seeing the opposite problem: no events at all.  I tried pullup mode, no change.
Things I am reading say I need a "timer" chip.  I've used LM555's before, but only as astable outputs.  The thing that confuses me the most is that at times the sensor actually worked with just the gpio.
I got the sensor from electrodragon, very little docs came with it.
I MUST get this working, but am running out of ideas.

Comment: You said the sensor (and your code) worked fine with NodeMCU 0.96. Did you try to go back for the heck of it?

Comment: I did but there's something about burning the new version that makes it hard to go back to the old one, I have new ones on the way.  (btw, "both" doesn't seem to work at all.)